# C# if powershell script end show message

Tags: c#, powershell, if-statement

If the script finished I want a messagebox popup, but I don't know the if statement.

```
    using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        PowerShellInstance.AddScript("cmdkey /list | ForEach-Object{if($_ -like \"*Target:*\"){cmdkey /del:($_ -replace \" \",\"\" -replace \"Target:\",\"\")}}");
        PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
        if ()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("the process was successfully completed");
        }
```

Comment: If you look at [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=netframework-4.8#System_Random_Next_System_Int32_System_Int32_) for `Invoke`, you'll see that it will *"Invoke the Command synchronously and return the output PSObject collection"*. So there's nothing to check (except perhaps catch one or more of the 12 documented exceptions that might be thrown on failure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PowerShellInstance.Invoke();` is synchronous, so your script will already wait for Powershell to complete. You don't need an `if` statement.

If you really want asynchronous execution you can invoke the script another way using `BeginInvoke()`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/kebab/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c - it explains both the synchronous and asynchronous approaches.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by ADyson, calling `PowerShellInstance.Invoke();` is synchronous.

However, if you want to know if the command was successful or not, you can use [`HadErrors`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.haderrors?view=pscore-6.2.0) and read the error stream when needed:

```cs
if (!PowerShellInstance.HadErrors)
{
    MessageBox.Show("the process was successfully completed");
}
else
{
    string[] errors = PowerShellInstance.Streams.Error.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
    // Show error to user or log them...
}
```